# c++ Template error in main function?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am using VS c++ 6.0.  I have read that 6.0 has some problems with templates??

OK... if I leave the declaration as:

```
template <class T> T jMin( T a, T b ){
    return ( a < b );
}
```

The function works, but doing as the following I get the error:

```
error C2039: 'jMin' : is not a member of 'CVid3Dlg'
```

Why is there a difference?... and this may relate to the previous post...

If I put the definition in the HEADER as follows, I get:

```
error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'T __thiscall CVid3Dlg::jMin(T,T)'
        With the following template arguments:
        'double'
```

// CVid3Dlg.h

```
class CVid3Dlg : public CDialog
{
public:
    CVid3Dlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL); // standard constructor
    template <typename T>  T jMin( T a, T b );

protected:
    HICON m_hIcon;
    bool PreViewFlag;

    BITMAP bm; //bitmap struct
    CBitmap m_bmp; //bitmap object
    CRect m_rectFrame; //capture frame inside main window
    bool firstTime;



    // Generated message map functions
    //{{AFX_MSG(CVid3Dlg)
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
    afx_msg void OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam);
    afx_msg void OnPaint();
    afx_msg HCURSOR OnQueryDragIcon();
    afx_msg void OnTimer(UINT nIDEvent);
    afx_msg void GetVideo();
    afx_msg void OnClose();
    afx_msg void testing();
    afx_msg void Imaging();
    afx_msg void exTemplate();
    //}}AFX_MSG
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

//CVid3Dlg.cpp

```
template <class T> T CVid3Dlg::jMin( T a, T b ){// <-- FAILS
    return ( a < b );
}

void CVid3Dlg::exTemplate()
{
    Image *im = new Image();
    int s=0;

    s = jMin((double)3, (double)4);

    CString s1;

    s1.Format("%d", s);
    MessageBox(s1);
}
```

Comment: Please show the part of the `CVid3Dlg` class where you declare that member function.

Comment: If you left the "? a : b" in comment, you return true or false cast into T.

Comment: is `jMin` defined within `CVid3Dlg`?

Comment: Please see... I added the header file

Comment: The result of `a < b` is `bool`, not `double` or anything else. What is this supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, you've made the template a member function of CVid3Dlg. Now in CVid3Dlg::exTemplate() you can use it as follows:

```
 CVid3Dlg::exTemplate() 
 {
       double min = jMin<double>(3.0, 3.1);

 }
```

Comment: The template inside CVid3Dlg must be declared with <typename T> instead of <class T>. Then you may pass any type (not just classes) as a template parameter. ('double' is a type, but not a class)

Comment: I made the switch and get the same error:  type double unexpected.... also note Microsoft actually says <class T> and <typename T> are interchangeable

Answer (score 2):

Well, the error tells you exactly what's wrong:

```
'jMin' : is not a member of 'CVid3Dlg'
```

If you write

```
template <class T> T CVid3Dlg::jMin( T a, T b ) { ... }
```

instead of

```
template <class T> T jMin( T a, T b ) { ... }
```

then you are saying that `jMin` is a member function of `CVid3Dlg`. If you haven't declared it like that then you'll get that error.

Comment: please see, I added in the header and get the next ERROR

Answer (score 2):

If you want jMin to be a template member function of CVid3Dlg, you have to put the template definition inside the class CVid3Dlg.

```
class CVid3Dlg
{
     template <class T> T jMin( T a, T b ){  
      return ( a < b );// ? a : b;  
     }     
};
```