# c++ arithmetic with unknown types:void pointers?

Tags: c++

(I want to deal with "void" I am avoid "template class" because it is too much trouble)

ok establish some ground

```
int aa=3;
int bb=4;
int cc=0;

int *a, *b, *c;

a = &aa;
b = &bb;
c = &cc;

*c = *a +*b; //yields 7
```

but I want to do the following:

```
void *va;
void *vb;
void *vc;

va = a;
vb = b;

*c = (int)(*va + *vb);  // <-- 3 errors see below
```

but I get errors:

```
 error C2100: illegal indirection
 error C2100: illegal indirection
 error C2110: cannot add two pointers
```

Comment: I want to deal with "void"  I am avoid "template class"

Comment: WHY???   what does it mean to add void to void?

Comment: What exactly is the deal? You want to add what they point to without knowing what it is?

Comment: Why do you prefer `void` over templates?  As if that were even a meaningful tradeoff that were possible to make (in most cases, it's not).

Comment: No you don't. Really. Read more about how templates work and try to make simpler examples to get the hang of them.

Comment: @KerrekSB, beautifully worded :)

Comment: look at my previous questions about templates

Comment: You mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288537/c-template-error-in-main-function? Whatever you are trying to do there, `void*` is not going to achieve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't dereference `void` pointer.

If you want to turn them into `int*` you should do that before dereferencing;

```
(*(int*)vc) = (*(int*)va) + (*(int*)vb);
```

But you better be more specific, what exactly you want to do that you call "the following".

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do many operations at all on truly unknown types in C or C++.

You could use Boost Variant to support multiple arithmetic types in one variable, or you could use a `union` and basically do what Boost Variant does by discriminating it yourself.  Or you could build a type hierarchy and have virtual methods to perform the operations you need.  But you can't perform arithmetic on values whose types have been completely [erased](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure).

Answer (score 0):

The `void` pointer is a special pointer, it specifically denotes the *absence* of a type. These are often used to provide storage to a caller who *does* know the type and can cast back and forth.

Dereferencing a `void*` makes no sense and is, in-fact, invalid syntax, the whole point of dereferencing a pointer is to get the item being pointed to, if you don't specify *what* you're pointing at, you cant get it.

To "fix" your code you'd need to cast before dereferencing: http://www.ideone.com/eKxxn

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
        int ia = 1, ib = 2, ic = -1;

        int *a = &ia, *b = &ib, *c = &ic;
        void *va, *vb;

        va = a;
        vb = b;

        *c = (int)(*static_cast<int*>(va) + *static_cast<int*>(vb));
        std::cout << *c; // Outputs "3"
}
```